# How to change the data in ALL the textfields in a page to uppercase on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield, uppercase

I have a page with some 13 textfields. I want to change the case of data in all the textfields to uppercase on click of a button. I can either user Jquery/javascript. I definitely don't want to use CSS-Text-transform property since it does not convert the case actually but just virtually.

Any suggestions as of how can I achieve this task using a single function ?

Thanks,
Yeshwanth

Comment: I tried with undefined's method.

Comment: @YeshwanthKota - The commenter above you meant to ask you what have you tried prior to asking this question. It is usually frowned upon in the community if someone asks how to do certain things without even trying or researching. But you can forget it now as you have a solution!

Comment: @YeshwanthKota - if you have used `undefined`'s answer successfully, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: @bPratik : thanks for letting me know what I should have known well before :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `val` method:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('input[type=text]').val(function(i, oldVal){
       return oldVal.toUpperCase()
   })
})
```

Comment: just a reminder - make sure you have correct character encoding in your HEAD, otherwise JavaScript might not uppercase special UTF-8 characters as you would expect

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').each(function(index, value){
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you use something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type === 'text') {
        input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

If you don't mind using jQuery, something like this will work:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure JavaScript solution, if you are looking for one

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Make BIG" onclick="makeBig()" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function makeBig() {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
      for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
           if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text')
               inputs[i].value = inputs[i].value.toUpperCase();
       }
   }
</script>
```